# Solr Https Secure Certificate Password

Tags: https, solr, jetty

By default setting up Solr on Https requires storing the certificate password as plain text in "bin\solr.in.cmd" (using windows to host solr)
And the certificate password is exposed in the portal.

How can I configure Solr with a Https certificate keeping the certificate password safe?

I want to use a private certifcate so the client trusts the certificate by default, rather than a self signed one.
I'm connecting via SolrNet from C#, currently without authentiation, but in the future can look at Basic Authentication which is supported in the provider which wraps SolrNet.

Seems like a basic thing which I would have thought should be supported? Can't find any article/documention on this.
Anyone solved this already?

Nearest I've found is:

[Setting SOLR SSL properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48086035/128333)

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Prevent-the-SSL-Keystore-and-Truststore-password-from-showing-up-in-the-Solr-Admin-and-Linux-process-td4257422.html

Some suggestion of using jetty-https.xml and encrypt the configuration there.
Looking for a more complete answer.

---

### update

I've come across the following Solr tickets:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10307

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8897

Where support for loading the certificate passwords from environment variables has been added in Solr 7.0 and 6.7 (which hasn't been released yet).
I don't think using environment variables is much better, but some progress.
There is also a link to using Hadoop credential provider, but I'm not using Hadoop, so not applicable for me.

In the comments of the tickets, it mentions that someone tried the Jetty Password Utility, and Solr UI loaded over HTTPS. However the Collection API was erroring not being able to understand the password format.

So I'm still left without a way of configuring a certificate password for Solr, in a way I feel is secure.

Answer (score 1):

For me the certificate password is not stored on the SOLR portal

see my setup

**SSL**

`cd /path/to/solr/server/etc/`

The following command will create a keystore file named `solr-ssl.keystore.jks` in the current directory

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias solr-ssl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass secret -storepass secret -validity 9999 -keystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:@ipsolr,IP:127.0.0.1 -dname "CN=localhost, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx"
```

Convert the certificate and key to PEM format for use with Curl

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -destkeystore solr-ssl.keystore.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Next convert the PKCS12 format keystore into PEM format using the openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -in solr-ssl.keystore.p12 -out solr-ssl.pem
```

After go to your $JAVA_HOME (into jre/lib/security)

```
curl --cacert /pah/to/solr/server/etc/solr-ssl.pem https://localhost:8983/solr/
```

Set Common SSL-Related System Properties

`vi /etc/default/solr.in.sh`

```
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=JKS
```

Restart solr

`service solr restart`

**For authentication**
create security.json on SOLR_HOME (/var/solr/data/ for me)
Owner : root
See example of security.json to configure has you hope

After securing, add into `solr.in.sh`

```
SOLR_AUTH_TYPE="basic"
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:xxx"
```

it allows to have an answer on solr status service because with authentication it is not accessible

For me it's work and i don't see the certificate password on solr UI

Comment: what version of Solr are you on?

Comment: I use Solr 7.2.